# Error: invalid_request - invalid parameter for redirect_uri: Missing authority

Tags: cordova, oauth-2.0, hello.js

I've been working on and off for a few months on getting hello.js to work with my PhoneGap application.

Just focusing on Google for now, and when I get redirected in the PhoneGap browser, I'm sent to a 400 error;

```
Error: invalid_request
invalid parameter for redirect_uri: Missing authority
file:///android_asset/www/index.html
```

I've followed instructions on various sites to help with set up, but nothing seems to get me past this error.

My button:

```
<button onclick="hello( 'google' ).login()">google</button>
```

My javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hello.all.js"></script>
<script>
    hello.on('auth.login', function(auth){
        // call user information, for the given network
        hello( auth.network ).api( '/me' ).success(function(r){
            var $target = $("#profile_"+ auth.network );
            if($target.length==0){
                $target = $("<div id='profile_"+auth.network+"'></div>").appendTo("#profile");
            }
            $target.html('<img src="'+ r.thumbnail +'" /> Hey '+r.name).attr('title', r.name + " on "+ auth.network);
        });
    });
    hello.init({ 
        google   : 'MY_CLIENT_ID_IS_HERE.apps.googleusercontent.com'
    },{redirect_uri:'TRIED_VARIOUS_THINGS_HERE'});
</script>
```

I've tried a redirect url of http:// localhost (without the space as it is here)
I've tried a redirect url of urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
I've tried a redirect url of only oob

Google says my redirect URIS are

```
REDIRECT URIS  
urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
http://localhost
```

When speaking with Andrew Dodson, who I assume is the creator of hello.js he said:

```
Its like redirect_uri hasn't been set, it defaults to window.location.href,
```

He assured me that jQuery wasn't needed, but I was curious why the reference to var $target = $("#profile_"+ auth.network ); in the example code?

I don't use jQuery, and prefer just a Javascript solution. Is there someone who can explain the purpose of the $("... in the code above, and how I might use different code in it's place?

Thanks so much

Comment: I'm having the same issue now, did you ever get it solved?

Comment: No, I haven't been able to solve this problem. I'm curious why more people haven't interacted with this question to date. Thanks for your query- I hope you have better luck than I have!

Comment: I too have the same issue. No error, just opens the site again in a new window.  I added a `console.log('check');` in the `hello.on()` function and it will not fire it either.

Comment: Maybe if enough people have the error, a knowledgeable person will happen along and see the benefit of providing an answer! :)

Comment: For me it worked to add redirect_uri to init() rather than login(), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677421/hellojs-cordova-trouble-with-redirect-uri/