# HelloJS + Cordova: Trouble with redirect_uri

Tags: cordova, oauth-2.0, hello.js

I'm having some trouble using HelloJS with the Google+ API. It has been running nicely using a local development server, but when I try using it wrapped in a Cordova application, I'm getting an error.

Within the Google Development Console I've created a client id for web applications. 
The settings have been set as below;

[image]

On my phone I get a 400 Error "Invalid parameter for redirect_uri: Missing authority: file:///android_asset/www/index.html"

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly set

```
 hello.init( clientIds, {redirect_uri:'http://localhost/'})
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. It is now working. Is there possibly a difference between sending redirect_uri to init() vs login()? Because I'm pretty sure I tried setting it on the latter.